# Authentication failure reason in Vert.x Auth JWT

Tags: java, jwt, vert.x

How can I get some reason on why authentication fails when using JWT auth in vert.x library? For example when I send invalid JWT token I would like to know (programatically) the reason why is it invalid (expired, wrong issuer etc.). I use standard authentication handler:

`router.route("/api/v1/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwtAuth));`

The only thing I can get is HTTP status code 401 in response and this is not sufficient for me.

Comment: HTTP 401 mean UNAUTHORIZED and doesnt matter if expired, wrong issuer, ..) You need to redirect user to login page. This is standard behaviour.

Comment: @Peter1982 Yes, this is true. I was more thinking in context of logging/tracing. It is useful to know why the token was rejected. I don't want to expose that reason to client.

Comment: If you are token authority, you can send reason with error code 401. But for security reason, performance, ...  sending only HTTP code is the best option.

Comment: @Peter1982 I agree with you and I don't want to send reason to clients. I just want to know (on server side) the reason why was particular token wrong for the purpose of logging/tracing.